Existing AWS account with services invited to Organization
How to access the organization AWS RDS if they invited me with my personal account with the same service I already availed. What are the steps do I do to access both my personal and organization RDS?
I already read documentation regarding with the IAM but I'm still confuse how it works in my particular scenario.
